# UI sliders that control hardware, latency issue

Tags: user-interface, slider, hardware, updates, latency

I have a general UI question about how to work with sliders that control hardware.

Let's say I have a piece of audio hardware that is always reporting back the current volume it is set to. With this data being sent, it's possible to keep the UI slider set to the correct position.

The problem is that when the user moves the slider to update the hardware's volume, the user will often move the slider at a rate faster than the hardware reports back its current volume. The result is that as the user is moving the slider, the slider is continually jumping around as it changes its position every time volume data from the hardware is received.

There are a few solutions that I can see but they all seem really ugly and am wondering if their is a best-practice solution to what seems like is a very common problem.

Possible workarounds:

- Only send the new slider value to the hardware when the user stops sliding the slider

This isn't good if you want to hear the volume change as the slider is moved.

- While the user is moving the UI slider, don't update its value when hardware data is received.

The problem with this is that upon release, the hardware might not have "caught up" and the slider would snap to a different value that the user set it to.

e.g. maybe the hardware is moving a servo that takes time to reach a final position. The slider would 'request' a new position but it will take time for the hardware to reach that new position yet in the meantime its reporting back where it currently is positioned.

- Extend the above solution and add a timer delay to prevent the UI updating from the hardware source for a few seconds. During the delay, cache the latest hardware value.

In the servo example, there's still a chance that use may move the slider from 0 to 1 yet after the x sec delay, the servo is only at 0.5 so the slider snaps to 0.5 then slowly gets to 1.

- Create a non-standard slider that has a two slider-nubs, one that the user interacts with in order to 'set' the value and one that shows the current position/value of the hardware.

This all seems rather complex and am wondering if there is a standard way to do this.

Comment: How about: when the user moves the UI slider and releases it, disable the slider until the hardware catches up to the value. This seems more intuitive to me... as long as I am holding the UI slider I'd expect the values to keep changing, but when I am finished I would expect the value to [eventually] settle to my desired input.

Comment: I don't think that will work because it would lock the user out from being able to make a potentially critically important adjustment to the hardware. e.g. something really large and industrial like a crane.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to come up with a standard solution when you're dealing with such a huge variety of use-cases and potentially different hardware. In fact, you probably wouldn't want the same method for an audio device and something safety-critical, like a crane.
Another idea is to limit the speed at which your UI slider can move so that it matches the hardware. This might mean that the UI slider no longer has smooth operation but would instead jump to tiny intervals. If your hardware is quick enough this could be made to work.

Alternatively, I'd suggest looking at something other than a slider: arrows, for example. You can use up/down arrow buttons to increase/decrease the hardware value. Since your hardware reports its position back to you, you can then use that data to draw something on the UI (if you know your min and max limits, this works really well) and you circumvent the issue of your hardware keeping up with your UI because now it's the other way around.

Comment: I'll admit that my crane example was certainly at the extreme end. The typical use case is the hardware reporting back its current values within milliseconds of the user moving the slider to a new position; this results in the slider jumping about as it goes from being in the position the hardware is currently (because of the messages being sent from the hardware to the app) and where the user has currently dragged the cursor. It seems like a common issue that must have a common solution but I feel like I'm over complicating the potential solution.

Comment: @gmcc051 Is the slider your only option? It seems like it's causing a few problems for you. I once made a UI solution for moving a weight connected to a motor with a ball screw using up/down arrows. Pressing the arrow would send a command to the motor to move to its top or bottom position, and releasing the arrow would send a stop command to halt the motion. The UI would receive values from the motor and draw the correct image on-screen. It's simple but proved to be quite effective.